# Streams in Unix

Tags: linux, macos, unix, operating-system

Having read the reference I am not able to understand the real use of streams and where it is implemented in Unix.

So, what are streams in Unix?

Apart from the online references and books, can anyone summarize what you understanding of stream concepts (**not** I/O stream) is?
Also, what are the `putmsg` and `putpmsg` functions and how do they work?

Comment: Do you mean the console streams? Like 1 and 2? If so, see if this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29

Comment: No I didn't mention these stream. These are I/O streams. I asked about the streams related to kernel.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Is the part with `putmsg()` and `putpmsg()` connected to the streams question?

Comment: yes. It is related to that.